# Dynamically loading a couple of missing functions

Tags: macos, dyld, wcsdup

I have a binary, advertised as working on Mac OS X 10.6, but that tries to link `wcsdup()`, a function that was only added in 10.7. This is an extract from the bug report generated when launching on 10.6.8:

```
Process:         paradiseperfectboatrescue [149]
…
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [86]
…
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
…
Dyld Error Message:
 Symbol not found: _wcsdup
 Referenced from: …/Paradise Perfect Boat Rescue.app/Contents/MacOS/paradiseperfectboatrescue
 Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
…
```

The developer, for one reason or another, has not fixed the issue, reported ~6 months ago. I was wondering if there was any hope of circumventing the problem with programmatic tools. Specifically, would it be possible to instruct dyld to get `wcsdup()` from elsewhere? It is a simple function and assuming it is the only function missing, it can be implemented easily. Here is the implementation I would use, given the chance:

```
#include <wchar.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

wchar_t* wcsdup (const wchar_t *s)
{
  size_t len = wcslen(s) + 1;
  len *= sizeof(wchar_t);
  wchar_t *d = malloc(len);

  if (d)
    return memcpy(d, s, len);
  else
    return 0;
}
```

I have used `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in other circumstances, but then I wanted to help dyld to find entire libraries that it otherwise missed. This time my goal is not to provide an entire new library but to supplement the existing one with a few functions that use functions from the library being supplemented. Is it possible to tell dyld to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`, see here: http://tlrobinson.net/blog/2007/12/overriding-library-functions-in-mac-os-x-the-easy-way-dyld_insert_libraries/

This is like `LD_PRELOAD` on Linux...rather than giving a list of library paths to inspect for libraries an executable knows it needs, we load functions from a specific file and prevent searching for them elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, with the instructions from the page you link to, the program passes dynamic loading and starts to execute. It deadlocks a little bit later, but this is clearly not related (and I should probably give up on he idea of running on 10.6 a program that hasn't been compiled for it).

Answer (score 1):

For the record in case the page linked in John's answer goes away, here is what I did:

```
$ gcc -Wall -o wcsdup_ov.dylib -dynamiclib w.c
$ export DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1
$ export DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=$HOME/wcsdup_ov.dylib
$ open ~/Desktop/Paradise\ Perfect\ Boat\ Rescue.app
```

This helped make the application load, but execution gets stuck in a deadlock shorty after that.